# Unable to verify login through xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, gettext

I am trying to verify login by comparing 'welcome user' text with user name. The comapriosn is not matching. When I print xpath text with `elem.getText()`, it shows me additional text including the selected text.

Can anyone offer suggestions on how to write proper xpaths or write better code to verify login?

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ProfilesIni;

public class verify_loign 
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        WebDriver driver;
        ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
        FirefoxProfile fire_profile = profile.getProfile("sele_prac");
        driver=new FirefoxDriver(fire_profile);
        driver.get("https://phptravels.org/clientarea.php");
            driver.findElement(By.id("inputEmail")).sendKeys("rakeshm@techved.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("inputPassword")).sendKeys("123456");
        driver.findElement(By.id("login")).submit();
        WebElement verify_login_ele =     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='header-lined' and contains(h1,'Welcome Back, rakesh')]"));
//      String str = "Welcome Back, rakesh";
//      if(verify_login_ele.equals(str))
//      {
//          System.out.println("Your logged in succesfully");
//      }
//      else
//      {
//          System.out.println("Something went wrong with valid credential");
//      }
        System.out.println(verify_login_ele.getText());
        driver.findElement(By.id("Secondary_Navbar-Account")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("Secondary_Navbar-Account-Logout")).click();
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not everyone has account on phptravels.org... Can you share `HTML` of mentioned welcome message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just checked it with FirePath.

```
WebElement welcomeElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h1"));
```

There is only one h1 header on this site.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it's currently failing is because you are attempting to compare a WebElement object with text, which will always fail.  There are several alternative ways to do what you are trying to accomplish.

The quickest and simplest "fix" would be to insert .getText() before .equals(...

```
 if(verify_login_ele.getText().equals(str))
```

It is not the most elegant solution, but it would likely be all that is needed to make it work.

Don't fret, it's a beginner's mistake and you're doing well so far.